# Android Google maps application: getting error in android manifest.xml which is an lib file

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments

I am developing a simple Android app which uses the Google Maps API,
I had registered with Google for the API key and added it to my app but I am getting an error: [image]

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.s56.maps, PID: 866
12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.s56.maps/com.s56.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.s56.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  ... 11 more

***12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />***

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4784)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)

12-17 09:28:56.070: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  ... 21 more
```

And my XML file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.s56.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        />
    <permission
        android:name="com.s56.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.s56.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.s56.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="A***MY_API_KEY***M"/>

    </application>

    </manifest>     

      and my activity_main.xml has

<fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


 And my main class i.e activity class has,

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
  {     
  private GoogleMap mMap;         
 @Override     
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {         
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             
 mMap=
                                                                                               ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();         
     mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);         
    final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(17.426944259701596, 78.5340459823017);         
   Marker c = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()                              
   .position(CIU).title("s56 labs"));    

    }     
   @Override     
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {         
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.         
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);         
   return true;  
  } }
```

I had added Google Play services as library to Eclipse work space.

Kindly help me with this, and I am new to Android.

Comment: Copy and paste my answer just below "<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="A***MY_API_KEY***M"/>"

Answer (score 0):

You must add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Can you please mention it clearly., Like version..?? n value...??

Comment: If you take a look here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start there is a part that says "Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the <application> element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with."

Comment: I am getting new error while launching emulator as 
[2013-12-17 20:26:23 - Maps] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

[2013-12-17 20:26:23 - Maps] Please check logcat output for more details.

[2013-12-17 20:26:23 - Maps] Launch canceled!

Comment: Well it seems that there is another app installed with your package name (com.s56.maps) and it has a higher versionCode than yours. I suggest you to uninstall this application from your emulator or change  your package name and try again

Comment: 12-17 10:22:12.101: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1392): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3025110

12-17 10:22:12.121: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1392): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3025110

12-17 10:22:12.151: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1392): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3025110

12-17 10:22:12.201: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1392): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3025110

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1392): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3025110

Comment: It seems that this is a bug of Google Play services on the emulator. Try the following link to see if it solves your problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880